# Uncaught Error: Unrecognized extension value in extension set ([object Object])

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a code editor using [Sandpack](https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/). I am getting an error message in the console after integrating a `@codemirror/autocomplete` extension in the default `SandpackCodeEditor` component. But it's not showing an error message on the browser window, and I'm not able to write code in the code editor (I think after adding that extension, the code editor goes into read-only mode).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Error message:

```
index.js:1346 Uncaught Error: Unrecognized extension value in extension set ([object Object]). This sometimes happens because multiple instances of @codemirror/state are loaded, breaking instanceof checks.
```

[image]

My Code:

```
import {
  SandpackCodeEditor,
  SandpackConsole,
  SandpackLayout,
  SandpackPreview,
  SandpackProvider,
} from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";
import { autocompletion, completionKeymap } from "@codemirror/autocomplete";

export default function MySandpack() {
  return (
    <SandpackProvider>
      <SandpackLayout>
        <SandpackCodeEditor
          extensions={[autocompletion()]}
          extensionsKeymap={[completionKeymap]}
          showTabs
          showLineNumbers={false}
          showInlineErrors
          wrapContent
          closableTabs
        />
        <SandpackPreview />
        <SandpackConsole />
      </SandpackLayout>
    </SandpackProvider>
  );
}
```